# Чем может обернуться использование конвертации конструктора?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Чем может обернуться использование операторов конвертации конструктора/ов?

Есть класс, который не может физически работать без другого класса, оба класса являются обертками над неуправляемыми объектами. В свою очередь класс который не может работать без класса `vlc_instance`, имеет при себе конструктор конвертор из `vlc_instance` в `vlc_media_player`, класс `vlc_media_player` извлекает из `vlc_instance`, нативный указатель и использует его для работы с `vlc`. Все нормально, но в данные конструкторы можно передать как `vlc_instance`, так и `null` из [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Правильно ли делать проверку на `nullptr` в данном операторе, и в случае если он пуст, бросить исключение?

```
ref class vlc_instance;

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

public ref class vlc_media_player
{
private:
    vlc_instance ^ m_instance_;
    IntPtr m_player_;

public:
    vlc_media_player(vlc_instance^ instance);
    ~vlc_media_player();

    static libvlc_media_player_t* operator &(vlc_media_player^ value);
    static operator vlc_media_player ^ (vlc_instance^ value);
};
```

```
libvlc_media_player_t * vlc_media_player::operator&(vlc_media_player ^ value) {
    return reinterpret_cast<libvlc_media_player_t*>(value->m_player_.ToPointer());
}

vlc_media_player::operator vlc_media_player ^ (vlc_instance^ value) {
    if(value == nullptr)
    {
        throw gcnew NullReferenceException("value");
    }

    return gcnew vlc_media_player(value);
}
```

Как пример передачи `null`:

```
using System;
using vlc;
namespace vlc.tests
{
    class Program
    {
        private static vlc_instance _vlcInstance;
        private static vlc_media_player _mediaPlayer;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _vlcInstance = null;
            _mediaPlayer = _vlcInstance;
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам нужен перегруженный оператор `&`, кстати? Почему не просто метод, выдающий указатель?

Comment: Проверка входных данных на валидность — обязательна в уважающем себя коде. Поэтому да, конечно проверяйте.

Comment: @VladD: Удобнее делать извлечение при передаче чем производить вызов функции =)

Comment: Удобнее — может, но понятнее ли для читателя?

Comment: Ну и за вычетом `ref` и `NullReferenceException` у вас вопрос про C++, специфики .NET тут не видно.

Comment: @VladD: Нет, но пользователи вряд-ли будут пробовать извлекать нативные указатели на данные классы.

Comment: Тут вопрос не о пользователях класса, а о тех, кто будет читать _ваш_ код и пытаться понять его. Запутать код, чтобы выиграть две строчки — не самая хорошая идея. Попробуйте взглянуть на код глазами постороннего программиста: код должен быть интуитивно ясен.

Comment: @VladD: А проверку лучше произвести в конструкторе, или в операторе?

Comment: Если конструктор публичный, то в конструкторе. Если оператор публичный, то и в операторе тоже.